# Conditional upsell message

Tags: magento-1.8, product, php, up-sells

I have my upsells in a block on my product page as default but I would like to display a message or custom block in the same position as my upsells would go if a product has no upsells products ie "sorry this product has no upsell products".

This is my current upsell.phtml file

```
    <div class="upsells">

<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>


    <h2><?php echo $this->__('You might also like') ?></h2>

    <?php // $this->setColumnCount(5); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>

    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>



    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>

    <ul>

        <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>

            <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(225) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a>

                <h3 class="upsell-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>



              </li>  

            <?php else: ?>

            <div class="empty">Sorry we couldn't find any products simular to this</div>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endfor; ?>

    <?php endfor; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif ?>

</div><!-- end upsells -->
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the Upsell products template for this.
app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\list\upsell.phtml

Note: you may need to copy this file to YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME from:
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\upsell.phtml

The file contents are wrapped in and if statement:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
....list of upsell products 
<?php endif ?>
```

Change this to:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
....list of upsell products 
<?php else : ?>
....your custom code 'sorry this product has no upsell products'
<?php endif ?>
```

---

Edited answer

Your code is close but it looks like the 'else' content is in the wrong location (I also moved the closing ).  Try this:

```
<div class="upsells">

<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>


    <h2><?php echo $this->__('You might also like') ?></h2>

    <?php // $this->setColumnCount(5); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>

    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>



    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>

    <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(225) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a>

            <h3 class="upsell-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>



        </li>  

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endfor; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php endfor; ?>

<?php else: ?>

<div class="empty">Sorry we couldn't find any products simular to this</div>    

<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- end upsells -->
```

Comment: I already have that in my upsell.phtml but it doesnt work. I have edited my original question to show the content of my upsell.phtml file.

Comment: @DuggyG I've updated the answer with an edited version of your code that should provide what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Brilliant thankyou for your help Jason.